# SQL select attribute tupel in reversed order (not order by)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates

I have a mysql table with entries of my driver's logbook. In the table there are two columns: start_place and end_place. Sometimes it's possible, that end_place is equal to start_place (i think that sounds logical).

Now I wan't to select the entries of the table which occour as tupel (x,y), but not as (y,x).

Example:

```
id | start_place   | end_place
-----------------------------------
0  | New York      | San Francisco
-----------------------------------
1  | San Francisco | New York
```

The row with the id 1 is a duplicate of id 0 in reversed order and should not be part of the result.

Does someone has an idea? Several times I tried with subselects or where conditions like (x,y) != (y,x) but that doesn't work.

Comment: You should included the queries you have tried ..

Comment: You say you want to dismiss id 1 because of id 0. Would you also be ready to dismiss id 0 because of id 1 instead? Or does it matter which to dismiss and which to keep? Does the order matter at all? If you have a row with `x, y`, but no row with `y,x`, would it still be okay to show `y,x` instead of `x,y`?

Comment: Do nulls occur in start_place or end_place?

Comment: Can real duplicates occur, i.e. two records with `x,y`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: It doesn't matter which tupel is part of the result, (x,y) or (y,x). The order doesn't matter, yes, (x,y) is still okay ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `least` and `greatest` functions with a `group by`.

```
select least(start_place,end_place), greatest(start_place,end_place)
from tbl
group by least(start_place,end_place), greatest(start_place,end_place)
having count(*) = 1
```

To retrieve such rows with other columns, use

```
select *
from tbl
where (least(start_place,end_place), greatest(start_place,end_place)) 
in (select least(start_place,end_place), greatest(start_place,end_place)
    from tbl
    group by least(start_place,end_place), greatest(start_place,end_place)
    having count(*) = 1
   )
```

Comment: That's what I've searched for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEAST`, `GREATEST` and `DISTINCT` to get distinct pairs:

```
select distinct
  least(start_place, end_place) as place1,
  greatest(start_place, end_place) as place2
from mytable;
```